# Pandas Boolean Where Filtering: How can I use it for creating a real subset of the data?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, where-clause

In my case I have 1002 traces (in columns) of each 2560 samples (the rows).
I want to select a subset of traces for which the sample maximum is situated between two values.

```py
    filter1=(CCC.max()>=11850)&(CCC.max()<=12150)
    DDD=CCC.where(filter1,axis=0)
    EEE=DDD.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
```

I hoped that EEE contained just the traces as explained above. When calculating the maximum value per trace in EEE I get again all maxima.

From what I obtain I have the impression that the where filter is only a sort of a mask on the complete dataframe and not a real subset of the dataframe.

How can I make a real subset by take these columns where the boolean parameter True is.

----> On request from lostCode an example clarifying my question:

```py
data=([[0.5,1.0,2.0,3.0,0.7,5.0,4.0],
              [7.0,8.0,9.0,0.1,6.0,7.0,4.0],
              [1.0,2.0,3.0,0.4,5.0,6.0,7.0],
              [9.0,0.8,7.0,0.6,8.0,7.0,2.0]])
filter1=Data.max()<=8.0
Data=pd.DataFrame(data)
RRR=Data.where(filter1)
RRR.dropna()
```

The data array contains 4 rows being my traces of each 7 samples.
The maxima per row are:
row 0 5.0
row 1 9.0
row 2 7.0
row 3 9.0

Rows with max <=8.0 are row 0 and row 2.

I just want to copy the 2 rows in a dataframe I can then use for processing.

Comment: In this way you can select which elements to choose from a Data Frame, being able to choose several rows or columns depending on a condition.
Please if you can give an example of how your data looks and what you want the output to be. This would help us understand your problem. Thank you

Comment: If you DataFrame is CCC you can do `CCC.loc[(CCC.index.values>-11850) & (CCC.index.values <12150),:]`
Assuming that CCC only contains those columns you want to select.

Comment: Hi, I think this is a misunderstanding `where` does not have the same meaning as in SQL. It is a function to select between two values. And the indexer you use in where should have the same structure as the datafram. So e.g. if you use `filter1=(CCC>=11850)&(CCC<=12150)` your `where` condition will output `NaN` for all entries in your dataframe outside the given range. The way you call `where` it probably assumes False for all values, because it gets no index match and thus outputs NaN for each cell. But what you want to get is probably the `.loc`-result @lostCode proposed.

Comment: So if you want to compare the `where` methond with something familiar, it would not be the WHERE clause of SQL, but the `IF-ELSE` in python like in `mylist[0] if len(list)>0 else None`.

Comment: This happens because the `max ()` method evaluates by columns and not by rows. To do this you have to go through the rows individually

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=([[0.5,1,2,3,0.7,5,4],
              [7,8,9,0.1,6,7,4],
              [1,2,3,0.4,5,6,7],
              [9,0.8,7,0.6,8,7,2]])
Data=pd.DataFrame(data,columns='col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7'.split())
RRR=pd.DataFrame(columns='col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7'.split())
print(Data)
print('-'*100)
i=0
j=0
#this selects the rows that meet the condition and save it in RRR
while i<len(Data.index):
    if Data.loc[Data.index.values[i]].max()>8:
        RRR.loc[j]=Data.loc[Data.index.values[i]]
        j+=1
    i+=1
print(RRR)
print('-'*100)
print( 'max of colum 0: ',RRR.loc[0].max())
print('-'*100)
print( 'max of colum 1: ',RRR.loc[1].max())
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
0   0.5   1.0     2   3.0   0.7     5     4
1   7.0   8.0     9   0.1   6.0     7     4
2   1.0   2.0     3   0.4   5.0     6     7
3   9.0   0.8     7   0.6   8.0     7     2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
0   7.0   8.0   9.0   0.1   6.0   7.0   4.0
1   9.0   0.8   7.0   0.6   8.0   7.0   2.0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
max of colum 0:  9.0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
max of colum 1:  9.0
```

Comment: I do not think so as I do not intend to take part of the data between indices. I want to take the complete row if the max of the row is in a specific range. See the example I have added above.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to clarify my question I found that I should have inserted axis=1 in order to work on rows. By doing this I become the desired set of rows respecting the constraint.
The code became:

```
data=([[0.5,1.0,2.0,3.0,0.7,5.0,4.0],
              [7.0,8.0,9.0,0.1,6.0,7.0,4.0],
              [1.0,2.0,3.0,0.4,5.0,6.0,7.0],
              [9.0,0.8,7.0,0.6,8.0,7.0,2.0]])
Data=pd.DataFrame(data)
filter1=Data.max(axis=1)<=8.0
RRR=Data[filter1]
RRR
```

Comment: Clear! You have to change the axis if you want me to search the maximum by rows, I left you a comment.